# How do I get my tkinter picture viewer working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I've been trying to teach myself tkinter and wanted to make a program that would find all the pictures in the directory and sub-directories of a folder and then display them one by one with a button to either save the file into the "Yes", "Maybe", or "Skip" folders or simply delete the file.

Here's what I'm trying to get it to look like:
[image]

And here is my code which tries to do just that:

```
# Python 3.4

import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from send2trash import send2trash

tk_root = tk.Tk()
tk_root.title("Picture Viewer - Do I want to keep this picture?")
file_count = 0

p = path = 'C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\Desktop\\Test\\'
yes = lambda img: os.rename(img, p+'Yes\\Picture_{0}.jpg'.format(file_count))
maybe = lambda img: os.rename(img, p+'Maybe\\Picture_{0}.jpg'.format(file_count))
skip = lambda img: os.rename(img, p+'Skipped\\Picture_{0}.jpg'.format(file_count)) 
delete = lambda img: send2trash(img) # Note: os.remove('img.jpg') also works

def search(directory):
    global file_count
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() in ('.jpg', '.jpeg'):
                img = os.path.join(root, file)
                file_count += 1

                top_frame = Frame(tk_root)
                bottom_frame = Frame(tk_root)
                top_frame.pack(side='top')
                bottom_frame.pack(side='bottom')

                picture = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img))
                picture = tk.Label(tk_root, image=picture)
                picture.pack(side='top')

                button_yes = Button(top_frame, text="Yes", command=lambda x=img:yes(x))
                button_maybe = Button(top_frame, text="Maybe", command=lambda x=img:maybe(x))
                button_skip = Button(top_frame, text="skip", command=lambda x=img:skip(x))
                button_delete = Button(bottom_frame, text="Delete", command=lambda x=img:delete(x))

                button_yes.pack(side='left')
                button_maybe.pack(side='left')
                button_skip.pack(side='left')
                button_delete.pack(side='bottom')
    print('All done!')
search('Test')
```

However, the problem is after I launch the program it isn't working well at all. It simply moves the first picture, "1.jpg", into whatever folder I pick (or delete) and then giving the following error if I try to sort another image:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified: 'Test\Example.jpg' ->
>   'C:\Users\Vale\Desktop\Test\Maybe\1.jpg'

Perhaps most importantly the images are not displaying and cycling properly. It is just a gray box in the middle each time. How do I get my program to work? I'm aware I need to get the image to appear still and something needs to be done to get the program to move onto the next picture as well (so I don't get FileNotFoundError for trying to sort the same picture twice), but I'm unsure what to do differently after watching tutorials and reading documentation.

Comment: `FileNotFoundError` means it couldn't find the file with the path it thinks it should be using. Does that file exist where you think it is? If so, you can use some basic print debugging to have Python tell you where it's actually looking, and then you can see how the path it's using differs from the path it should be using.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3  The file doesn't exist there for the maybe() because it is already moved from yes() ... My first and main problem is that the yes(), maybe(), and so forth at the beginning at being called at all without the button activating them.

Comment: `bind` always expect function name without `()` and arguments - if you use function with () then python calls this function and use value returned by this function as argument for `bind`

Comment: btw `Button` has `command=` to assign function so you don't need `bind` - but `command` expects function name (without `()`) too.

Comment: @furas Ah, that would make a lot of sense, thank you! Do you know how I can rewrite the bind function so that when the button is clicked it processes the current image through the selected option?

Comment: `lambda` should help `Button( ..., command=lambda:yes(img)) ` or `bind("<Button-1>", lambda event:yes(img))` . `bind` sends to function information about event so I use variable `event` in `bind` to receive this information.

Comment: but it can be problem because you use `img` in loop - and `lambda` doesn't copy value form `img` to yes(), it uses refence to `img` (but value in `img` is changing in loop so every `lambda` use the same value) - it is safer to use `command=lambda x=img:yes(x)` or `bind(..., lambda event, x=img:yes(x))`

Comment: @furas That is helping, thank you very much! However the image still isn't appearing (thankfully the buttons are though) and I get a FileNotFoundError after the first use of a button due to it trying to use the action on the same file it just moved. Any more ideas?

Comment: there is known problem with `PhotoImage` (used inside function) and disappearing image (removed by `"garbage collector"`)

Comment: problem with `FileNotFoundError` is because `lambda` in `command` or `bind` remember old path. You will have to assign/bind new `lambda`. Or you could create widget for one image with all buttons and add some other function which change button behavior.

Comment: @furas wouldn't every command / bind be re-assigned after each image because it is all nestled within a for loop (for file in files)?

Comment: Nope, due to `lambda` scoping rules. Change `button_yes = Button(top_frame, text="Yes", fg="green")` to `button_yes = Button(top_frame, text="Yes", fg="green", command=lambda img=img: yes(img))`. Then remove the `bind`s.

Comment: I think this code is beyond repair because that's simply not how GUIs work. You have a loop there which creates more and more `Frame` and `Button` instances and your loop also tries to ”run” the program. With GUIs your code should not be doing this but the main loop of the GUI framework should drive the program. Which means you need an object oriented approach to remember and manage the state of your program. This way you'd also get rid of the `global`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by BlackJack, your code creates the GUI Widgets over and over. You'll need to move that out from the loop. Also for displaying the image in the `Label`, you can't use `picture` as the name for both the `ImageTk` object and `Label` object.

Suggestions to changes. You could use a Generator to get the image path/filename. And make regular functions instead of using lambda. I had an interest in seeing how it could work, so I made the program below based on your code. When I tested it I had different paths, working on OSX, so haven't tested it with your Windows paths (that I put into the code here).

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

tk_root = tk.Tk()
tk_root.title("Picture Viewer - Do I want to keep this picture?")
file_count = 0

p = path = 'C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\Desktop\\Test\\'


def search(directory):
    global file_count
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in files:
            if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() in ('.jpg', '.jpeg'):
                img = os.path.join(root, file)
                file_count += 1
                yield img


def next_image():
    try:
        global photo_path
        photo_path = next(path_generator)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(photo_path))
        picture.configure(image=photo)
        picture.image = photo
    except StopIteration:
        picture.configure(image='', text='All done!')


def move_file(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    new_file = directory + 'Picture_{0}.jpg'.format(file_count)
    os.rename(photo_path, new_file)


def yes():
    move_file(path + 'Yes\\')
    next_image()


def maybe():
    move_file(path + 'Maybe\\')
    next_image()


def skip():
    move_file(path + 'Skipped\\')
    next_image()


def delete():
    # Code for deleting file here
    next_image()

top_frame = Frame(tk_root)
bottom_frame = Frame(tk_root)
top_frame.pack(side='top')
bottom_frame.pack(side='bottom')

path_generator = search(p)
photo_path = next(path_generator)

photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(photo_path))
picture = tk.Label(tk_root, image=photo)
picture.image = photo
picture.pack(side='top')

button_yes = Button(top_frame, text="Yes", command=yes)
button_maybe = Button(top_frame, text="Maybe", command=maybe)
button_skip = Button(top_frame, text="skip", command=skip)
button_delete = Button(bottom_frame, text="Delete", command=delete)

button_yes.pack(side='left')
button_maybe.pack(side='left')
button_skip.pack(side='left')
button_delete.pack(side='bottom')

tk_root.mainloop()
```

**EDIT:**

One issue with this code seems to be that it runs through the subdirectories (Yes, Maybe, Skipped). So you'll be presented with the images twice if it is in the path and then moved.

If you don't want to traverse the Yes, Maybe and Skipped folders, you can change the `search` function to:

```
def search(directory):
    global file_count
    excludes = ['Yes', 'Maybe', 'Skipped']
    for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory, topdown=True):
        subdirs[:] = [d for d in subdirs if d not in excludes]
        for file in files:
            if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() in ('.jpg', '.jpeg'):
                img = os.path.join(root, file)
                file_count += 1
                yield img
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you so very much! This works exactly the way I was aiming for and you managed to do it using the majority of the same code I had so I can actually understand it. I can't wait to keep learning more and try to make it look better now that it actually works, haha. Thank you so much again, I had been stuck pretty hard and this is just what I needed. :)